# What's the difference between a member and a default member in javascript imports?

Tags: javascript, import

I was reading about javascript imports [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and came across the concept of members vs default members but couldn't find an explanation of what the difference is. What is the benefit of declaring a class as `default` other than not having to include the name in brackets when importing?

Answer (score 1):

Because there's also [2 ways to export stuff from a module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):

regular `export` which exports per member

```
// module.js
export foo
export bar

// The dependent
import {foo, bar} from './module';
```

and `export default` which defines the default export.

```
// module.js
export default Foo

// The dependent
import Foo from './module';
```

As for advantages, it depends on the use case. Some libraries export APIs on a per member basis, which you can import individually. Others export everything in one object as the default export. Code bundlers like Rollup use per-member imports as a way to tree-shake unneeded imports during bundling as well.